# Trying to write files to an Excel document

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm writing a program that asks the user for a directory. Iterates through that directories files (depending on the extension), and then outputs it to an excel document.

Then if it fins a match. Add it to the Excel file which I have also created.
But I can't get it to write to the Excel.

```
import glob, os
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


folder = askdirectory()

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('panels.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Start from the top.. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0


os.chdir(folder)
for file in glob.glob("*.NAM"):
    worksheet.write(col, row, file)
    col=0
    row+=1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure your input folder contains .NAM files? This code works for me

Comment: yep - if I try to debug it by printing to the console. It works fine.

Comment: It seems if I mode workbook.close ABOVE os.chdir(folder). A excel file is written.. but I can't get access to my file data.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.. the file was created in the folder I chose to read the files from.. doh!